# 2カラム構成の場合のページ内スクロール

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

[このような](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)ライブラリを利用して、
ページ内スクロールを実現したいのですが、どれも動きません。

原因はHTMlが2カラム構成(それぞれスクロールが独立)しているためと思われます。

試しに[こちら](https://codepen.io/23gv4u23v5u2/pen/OJvWRLj)で試したところ、
右カラムの最下部にある`TOP1`ボタンは動作しませんが、`TOP2`ボタンは動作しました。

このようなライブラリはターゲットが`window.`に固定されているのだと思いますが、
解決する方法、もしくはそちらを指定できるものはありそうでしょうか？
またはHTML側のつくりを変えるべきでしょうか？

検証では(0,0)ですが、
実際はスクロール先の要素を指定し、アニメーションもしたいためライブラリに頼らないと大変そうです。

Comment: 冒頭に挙げられているreact-scrollでいえば、サンプル With-overflow にあるのがまさにそれではないですか？

Comment: まさにそれでした。
ありがとうございました。助かりました。